# Implemeting Zip(*iterables) using a For loop

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to implement the `zip(*iterables)` function using a for loop and I am unable to do it. As you know, the zip function gets the first element of every list that's passed into it, puts it in a tuple, then does the same with the second list of the elements in the list... and so on. In my case, I have been only able to do it with the first element.

This is as far as I got:

```
def inputlist(input_list):
    returned_list = []
    for i in input_list:
        for j in range(len(i)):
            returned_list.append(i[j])
            break

    return returned_list
```

FYI: This is purely for academic purposes and we are doing this just for the fun of it.

As an example, here's the list that I am passing: [[2,3,4], [5,6,7], [8,9,10]]

Comment: don't give `list` as a variable name. secondly, what is `len(i)`?

Comment: Sorry. I've changed it. `len(i)` would now make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a zip implementation w/o `zip()`.

For simplicity I did not handle the case of which the zip is bailing out when the number of elements is not in the same length.
The pitfalls in your original code were the `break` that actually canceled one of the loops and the fact that you should have append the outer element 'j' with the inner value.

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

def inputlist(lst):
    inner_len = len(lst[0]) #in szip it isactually the minimum length of all the items
    returned_list = [[] for _ in range(inner_len)]
    for i in lst:
        for j in range(len(i)):
            returned_list[j].append(i[j])

    return returned_list

print(inputlist(lst))  # --> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. I will mark this once I've comprehended it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure how exactly you want to zip your list. So you have one list and want to zip always the two consecutive items in that list?
Because your function only takes one list as input.

Generally, for combining two list, you can try the following:

```
def listzip(list1, list2):
    return zip(list1,list2)
```

This will construct a zip object, containing the zipped pairs from the original two lists.

Comment: MY apologies. I've updated what I am inputting. FYI, it's a list like this: `[[2,3,4], [5,6,7], [8,9,10]]`

Comment: Okay thank you. So you have a list of lists. And now you want to zip all the first elements, second elements and so forth?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but I may have already found the answer from below. Thanks for taking a look though.